# How to deploy Python Script that requires environment variables

Tags: python, deployment, .env

As the title says, I have a Python script I wrote that I would like to allow others to use.

The script is an API aggregator, and it requires a client_id and secret to access the API. As of now I have an env file which stores these values and I'm able to get the values from the env file.

My question is now that I have finished the script locally, how do I deploy with the environment variables it so others can use it given that the environment variables are required?

Sorry if this is a simple question - new to writing scripts for others to use.

The only thing I could think of was including the .env when I push to github, but not sure if that's great practice since my client_id and secret are stored there

Comment: Generally, you document the required environment variables.

Comment: What exactly do you want to know: how to read environment variables, how to set environment variables or something else?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga in the document would I include the value for the variable? The thing is other users won't know the values for these variables, and I guess my issue is I don't want them to see the variable values either

Comment: Your exact situation is not clear, are you expecting other users to have  to use *your* API key/credentials ?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga yes that was the idea. The point of the script is to make accessing specific data from the API simple enough for people who don't know how to write a line of code to use. They run the script from the command line with arguments for what data they want. (I would provide documentation to walk them through how to execute with the command line)

Comment: @aethernyx well, it's going to be hard to let them use your credentials without them having access to those credentials. I think you are going to have to think about exactly how to handle that.